# Managing disk space with > 500 virtual windows servers (strategy ?)

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization

I'm working as an admin in a medium sized company. Over the last 10 years our amount of servers increased from less than 90 physics to more than 500 virtual machines including a few physics as host servers.

We're using VMWare as host and our clients are mostly Windows servers. Some 2003, most 2008 R2 and a few 2012 R2. SCOM 2007 R2 is used as monitoring tool (a bit customized).

Averagely we weekly get 5 alerts for servers which meet the threshold of insufficient disk space. 
For application (gateway or processing machines) we mostly have scheduled tasks which are deleting aged logs. For E-Mail we have an archiving solution in place to keep the DBs from filling - but for rest 90% of various machines just extension is applicable ...

I'm wondering how you are managing disk space in your environments?
What's your strategy? 
- Or is there a tool / mechanism which can extend virtual disks on demand semi-automated?

Many thanks in advance

Ruben

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're not provisioning your virtual disks with enough capacity to begin with.  Windows in particular tends to grow the base OS footprint quite a bit due to hotfixes over the course of several years.  The newest versions of Windows (8.1/2012 R2) mitigate this to a certain extent with some default scheduled tasks that cleanup superseded update files.  And there are some additional manual steps you can take to squeeze a bit more (google "dism sxs cleanup").  But it's not something you should count on.

Personally, I don't like to create Windows VMs with less than a 60GB system disk.  In my experience, it has been enough to accommodate 5+ years of basic OS growth with room to spare assuming you don't have applications or people filling up the disk with other stuff.  The goal is to not be in the situation where you're scrounging to free up a gig here or a gig there.  That's just busy work that your employer shouldn't need to pay someone to do.  Buying more disk is cheaper.  So plan for larger images in advance.  Work it into your storage budget.

Thin provision if you want.  There's also a lot to be said for storage solutions with de-dupe capability.

Comment: To me the 60 GB of system disk makes sense. Presently we have 40 GB, but I happen to see that just 6 GB are left after having them patched over 3 years circularly. The SXS folder is a beast ... 

De-dupe will be interesting once we migrated our file-servers to 2K12 R2.

Thank you for the suggestions :)

Comment: I was actually referring to de-dupe at the VM storage layer; whatever your vmdk files live on (SAN, NAS, etc). Lots of Windows VMs means lots of identical OS files on blocks that can be de-duped.